# Create a dataset of images - Kinect

Tags: dataset, kinect, rgb, depth

I need to record a new RGB-D Kinect dataset for people detection. I did some research on the datasets available but non of them can fit my criteria.

Does anyone have any experience recording a dataset: programs, annotate the dataset..etc